# dotnetOpenAuth fails on protocol error. Is it ServiceProviderDescription ot TokenManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

Why do I get `openAuth protocol error` ?

> {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, DirectWebRequestOptions options) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\StandardWebRequestHandler.cs:line
>   126

```
    public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription ServiceDescription = new  ServiceProviderDescription
{
    RequestTokenEndpoint = 
       new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://www.google.com/account/OAuthGetRequestToken", HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest),
    UserAuthorizationEndpoint = 
       new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken",
HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest),
    AccessTokenEndpoint = 
       new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken", HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest),
    TamperProtectionElements = 
       new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
  };



public void StartOAuth()
{
    var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumer.ServiceDescription, new InMemoryTokenManager("user", "pass"));
 // Url to redirect to
    var authUrl = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
 // request access
    consumer.Channel.Send(consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(authUrl, null, null));

      throw new NoRedirectToAuthPageException();
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this would cause the error you're seeing, but you're passing in Google's own URL in as the callback URL?  That seems wrong.  You need to pass in the URL to your own site (the one that will call `WebConsumer.ProcessUserAuthorization`) in as the first parameter to the `PrepareRequestUserAuthorization` method.

I also notice that you're missing an "s" in your request token URL: `https://www.google.com/account*s*/OAuthGetRequestToken`

That will very likely break it.

Comment: I still run on localhost. Tried to change to some local host url, but it didn't help. I want to use DNOA, but I think it's missing something in the headers that appears in http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/

Comment: Updated answer with the likely culprit.